# Understanding dev/prod deployment with git

Tags: git, deployment, branch

I've been reading a lot about git branching models and pretty sure I understand the process behind that. So i've been pushing all of my changes for a website (using PHP) up to a centralized repo (origin). this is just a bare repository. However, I'd like to get this code into a test environment. What is a recommended way of handling this? I've read plenty of articles that simply checkout the git working tree to the web root but i'd like it to be cleaner then that.  This doesn't seem to work well with multiple developers working on the project. This would go the same for the production side as well. Does it make sense to have a non-bare that I pull into from origin?

Any insight/comments/thoughts on this to help me move in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a multi-dev project, IMO the best/easiest way is to create a branch for each portion and/or member of the group, and have them commit their changes there. Once a given piece of the project is done, or changes on the branch are done and tested, you could merge them back to the master (which I am assuming you meant by "orgin"). So, long story short, I would create branches  for each dev, or project, and then commit your changes to the branch, and once done with the branch merge with master. But, that is just my opinion/experience with app dev and java work, there may be a better way depending on your project. Cheers and goodluck!

EDIT: For Windows, I like TortoiseGit, I think the GUI helps a bit for new users.

- https://tortoisegit.org/

For OSX I love/use daily SourceTree:

- http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: thanks for the response. yes, i said origin in hopes to capture it being a remote repo. i guess since you are developing in java, you might have a continuous build server which i would not have. i should mention my development is in php. so guess the question is, would i put a non-bare repo in my docu root of my dev system and pull from remote master? repo dev branch? that is where i'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing PHP, so I'll answer from that perspective.

I have a project set up now with two main branches, `master` and `develop`. All completed features get merged with `develop` and, after testing, `develop` gets merged into `master`.

To your question of deployment, I would recommend against just checking out into web root since that will also put repository details in that directory that shouldn't be there and theoretically could cause merge problems or have a higher rate of accidentally overwriting production data that's not in the repository, like config files or saved PDF or something. It's also a possible security issue if not handled properly.

I would recommend doing deploys using something like [Phing](http://www.phing.info/). Using Phing, I can run `phing test-release` from my command line and have it:

1. Checkout `develop` and make sure it's up to date
2. Move the files I want deployed to a directory tree as it will appear on the server
3. SSH the files to the test server
4. Move all test config files to their proper location
5. Run any database migrations that need run
6. Push the `develop` branch to `origin`
7. Push the `develop` branch to my personal backup repository

The nice thing about this is, it's amazingly easy to run once set up and I already know that it won't overwrite anything I don't want it to. I also copied that same script, changed some directory paths and git branch names and have a `phing www-release`. You would also be able, if needed in the future, to have this ready for an integration server (which is still a good idea, even if you use PHP).

The key, I guess, is git is not a deployment tool and will probably cause headaches later on if you try to use it that way for any non-trivial application.

Comment: right. i think that is part of my issue. i think i've been considering git as a deployment mechanism. this is probably where i've gone wrong. let me review what you've answered. thanks for pointing out at least that so far. actually helps me out a lot.